# adding cross browser jscrollpane not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am using [this](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) 
 to change the default scroll-bar and this is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/275/)
In the fiddle I am writing this  `<div class="scroll-pane horizontal-only">`(line number 122 in html section) to change the default scroll bar but If i write this then the whole div disappears.[This](http://jsfiddle.net/tonyjose009/4GP9c/274/) shows before use of jscrollpane.

this is the jquery

```
$(function()
            {
                $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
            });
```

Line number 213 in js section and this is the css

```
/* Styles specific to this particular page */
            .scroll-pane
            {
                width: 100%;
                height: 200px;
                overflow: auto;
            }
            .horizontal-only
            {
                height: auto;
                max-height: 200px;
            }
```

Line number 118 in the css section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Era said jScrollpane is having a `height: 0`, it's not getting what the height of the parent is as the tab is hidden on load.

I changed the code such that it executes only after the tab is visible.

```
<a id="userlink" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Users</a>

$('body').on('shown', '#userlink', function () {
    if(!$('.scroll-pane').hasClass('jspScrollable')) {
      $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
    }
})
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/4GP9c/282/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1,well can you please tell me where(line numbers) in the html/css you have changed.?

Comment: In the fiddle, line 215(js) and line 6(html)

Comment: what do I need to do for horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: Oh I missed that. You need to give immediate children of scroll-pane a width for eg: 1000px. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/4GP9c/283/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Well do you have experience in bootstrap?

Comment: @JqueryLearner Good to know the solution worked. Yes, I have worked on bootstrap.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44263/discussion-between-jquerylearner-and-anpsmn)

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle, jScrollpane is having `height:0` this is because jScrollpane will take the height of parent or as per the parent container. you need to set some height to the parent then only it will show up.

Comment: Thanks for answering,can you give me an working fiddle?

Comment: I did as you said ,now the div appears but the scroll bar does not show up.Can you give me a working fiddle?

Comment: I tried a lot dear .. but there is some kind of conflict between your bootstrap-combined.min.css and jscrollpane .. when I removed your css then it worked. and its really difficult to debug that issue in fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your help.well I am trying with this http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll/ now but I dont know how to add horizontal scroll bars.Do you have any idea for this?